# Angularjs - Uncaught Error angular.js:78

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am new to Angular and am playing around with ngRoute. For some reason, I keep getting the error listed even though I am loading the angular-route.js module. I think there might be some issues with the paths as well but I can't find the solution. The code is pasted below. The important files are student.js and student.html. angular.html and testCtrl.js are files for the simple calculator that I built that should be loaded when the link in student.html is clicked.

**student.js**

```
angular.module('testing', ['ngRoute'])  
    .config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/angular', {
            controller: "TestCtrl",
            templateUrl: 'angular.html'
        });
    })
```

**student.html**

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src = "student.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src = "testCtrl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app = "testing">
    <a href = "#/angular">Angular Calculator</a>
    <div ng-view></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

**angular.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app='testing'>
<head>
<title>Angular Calculator</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js">       </script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="testCtrl.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href = "angular.css" rel = "stylesheet">
</head>
<body id = "myBody">
<div ng-controller = "TestCtrl">
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<input class = "calculation-input" ng-model = "number1" placeholder = "Enter first number" id = "first" type = "text">
<br>
<input class = "calculation-input" ng-model = "number2" placeholder = "Enter second number" id = "second" type = "text">
<br>
<input ng-keypress = "calculate()" class = "calculation-input" ng-model = "operation" placeholder = "Enter an arithmetic operation here" id = "op" type = "text">
<br>
<input ng-click = "calculate()" type = "submit" value = "Submit" id = "calc">
<br>
<span id = "calculation">{{number1}}{{operation}}{{number2}}</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**testCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('testing', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller("TestCtrl", function($scope){
$scope.title = "Angular Calculator";

$scope.calculate = function(){
  var firstNumber = parseInt($('#first').val());
  var secondNumber = parseInt($('#second').val());
  var operation = $('#op').val();
  $('#calculation').html($scope.operate(operation, firstNumber, secondNumber));
}

$scope.operate = function(operation, firstNum, secondNum){
switch(operation){
  case '*':
    return firstNum * secondNum;
    break;

  case '+':
    return firstNum + secondNum;
    break;

  case '-':
    return firstNum - secondNum;
    break;

  case '/':
    return firstNum / secondNum;
    break;
  }
}
});
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the module twice:

**student.js**

```
angular.module('testing', ['ngRoute'])
```

**testCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('testing', ['ui.bootstrap'])
```

Where the second overrides the first. To fix the problem, declare all dependencies for the module in `student.js`:

```
angular.module('testing', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap'])
```

Then, to access the module later in `testCtrl.js`, call it without a second argument:

```
angular.module('testing')
.controller("TestCtrl", function($scope){
...
```

**Update**:

Also, Angular is designed for single page applications, so your template should be only a partial, not a complete HTML document as `angular.html` is in your code sample.

All of your scripts should therefore be loaded in `students.html`, and you should remove everything else wrapping the content meant to be shown in `ng-view`.

**student.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src = "student.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src = "testCtrl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href = "angular.css" rel = "stylesheet">
</head>
<body ng-app = "testing">
    <a href = "#/angular">Angular Calculator</a>
    <div ng-view></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

**angular.html**

```
<div ng-controller = "TestCtrl">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <input class = "calculation-input" ng-model = "number1" placeholder = "Enter first number" id = "first" type = "text">
    <br>
    <input class = "calculation-input" ng-model = "number2" placeholder = "Enter second number" id = "second" type = "text">
    <br>
    <input ng-keypress = "calculate()" class = "calculation-input" ng-model = "operation" placeholder = "Enter an arithmetic operation here" id = "op" type = "text">
    <br>
    <input ng-click = "calculate()" type = "submit" value = "Submit" id = "calc">
    <br>
    <span id = "calculation">{{number1}}{{operation}}{{number2}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked when I did `angular.module('testing', [])`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean because `angular.module('testing', [])` doesn't inject your dependencies. Are you saying that you followed my answer above or something else?

Comment: For some reason, when I followed the answer, I was still getting the error. When I added the [], the error was gone but the ng-view is not loading.

Comment: Adding the `[]` just overwrites the first declared module, which is why you're not seeing `ng-view` loaded

Comment: `[]` should definitely be removed. The error remains because of another issue. Check out the update I just made to my answer.

Comment: Okay so I need to move all the script tags in angular.html into student.html. Can you explain what you mean by the second part "remove everything...in ng-view."

Comment: ... meaning you have a complete HTML document which you don't need. So, remove head, title, body, etc. so you are left with just what is meant to appear in the view.

Comment: Something still is not working. Is it possible for you to make the edits that you mention on my code so I can see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Just updated my answer. These comments are getting a bit long in the tooth. I'd open a chat but you don't have enough rep points. So, please contact me privately if you continue to have issues.